# Hide css in iframe if text contains a specific word

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom, iframe

I need to hide a div that loads a javascript element in an iframe.
The div to hide must contain the text "Next"

Example:

```
<div class="alignNext">
<div class="inlineBlock nextAlign" elname="next"><button class="fmSmtButton next_previous navWrapper" type="button" elname="next" onclick="gotoNextPage(this);">
<em> Siguiente </em>
</button></div></div>
```

I have tried with

```
  <script>
  var divs = document.querySelectorAll(".alignNext");
Array.from(divs).forEach(function(div) {
  if (div.textContent.indexOf("Siguiente") >= 0 ) {
    div.style.display = "none";
  }
});
  </script>
```

But it doesn't work with the iframe.

The iframe code is:

```
<div id="zf_div_IsBaC6OI1EsmTbQpQNijKuyc2G6W7voKPIu077b1tZY"></div><script type="text/javascript">(function() {
try{
var f = document.createElement("iframe");   
f.src = 'https://forms.zohopublic.eu/how/form/SACMDPAGINADO/formperma/IsBaC6OI1EsmTbQpQNijKuyc2G6W7voKPIu077b1tZY?zf_rszfm=1';
f.style.border="none";                                           
f.style.height="278px";
f.style.width="90%";
f.style.transition="all 0.5s ease";// No I18N
var d = document.getElementById("zf_div_IsBaC6OI1EsmTbQpQNijKuyc2G6W7voKPIu077b1tZY");
d.appendChild(f);
window.addEventListener('message', function (){
var zf_ifrm_data = event.data.split("|");
var zf_perma = zf_ifrm_data[0];
var zf_ifrm_ht_nw = ( parseInt(zf_ifrm_data[1], 10) + 15 ) + "px";
var iframe = document.getElementById("zf_div_IsBaC6OI1EsmTbQpQNijKuyc2G6W7voKPIu077b1tZY").getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0];
if ( (iframe.src).indexOf('formperma') > 0 && (iframe.src).indexOf(zf_perma) > 0 ) {
var prevIframeHeight = iframe.style.height;
if ( prevIframeHeight != zf_ifrm_ht_nw ) {
iframe.style.height = zf_ifrm_ht_nw;
}   
}
}, false);
}catch(e){}
})();</script>
```

You can see the project at https://codepen.io/dlopezros/pen/GRjrgwQ

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try this

```
JQuery(".alignNext").css("display","none");
```

Comment: it doesn't work, because it should only be hidden when it contains the word "Next"

Comment: could you spot the word next in the javascript code? or send that piece of code?

Comment: Can you explain what you ask?
I need help, thanks

Comment: Could you please clear that where the word "Next" is loaded in the javascript code? Can you send the link or image containing the code?I  Cant see the next in the iframe code

Comment: You can see the project at https://codepen.io/dlopezros/pen/GRjrgwQ